# What is the Swift equivalent for Java's Comparator Interface

Tags: swift

I have the following Java code below that I am trying to convert into Swift accordingly. Can somebody help me on this issue. Thanks

```
public class CarsSortById implements Comparator<Cars>{

@Override
public int compare(Cars car1, Cars car2) {
    return (car1.getCarId() < car2.getCarId()) ? -1: 
    (car1.getCarId() > car2.getCarId() ) ? 1:0 ;
   }

}
```

Comment: Why not use a lambda for this, anyway?

Answer (score 9):

## Swift equivalent of [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Is the [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) protocol. It requires that your type define an `<` operator. Since it derives from the `Equatable` protocol, you need to define the `==` operator, as well:

```
class Car {
    let id: Int
    // other fields
}

extension Car: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension Car: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id
    }
}
```

## Swift equivalent of [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

In Java, `Comparator` is an interface that lets you define sorting functions in addition to the one a type defines for itself via the `Comparable` Interface. Interfaces like this are necessary because Java didn't support lambdas prior to 1.8. And after Java 1.8, interfaces form the basis of lambdas.

Swift doesn't have an equivalent interface (called a protocol, in Swift). There's no need, since Swift can let you just define closures without the `@functionalinterface` cruft of Java.

Usually, Java Comparators are only used once. In this case, just call sort with a custom sorting closure:

```
let carsSortedByID = cars.sorted { $0.id < $1.id }
```

If you need to resume the sorting closure, you could assign it to a variable. Naturally, it would make sense to store these as static variable in an extension on the type that they sort.:

```
extension Car {
    static let idSorter: (Car, Car) -> Bool = { $0.id < $1.id }
}

let carsSortedByID = cars.sorted(by: Car.idSorter)
```

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, but I got your point and agree on that.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in other answers and in the comment, in swift there is nothing for that. It is just closure.

But here is how you define [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable)

```
class Car {
    var id = -1
}

extension Car: Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    static func < (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
          return lhs.id < rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Java's `Comparable` is different from `Comparable`

Comment: @Alexander thats how the swift standard library is designed. Array type has a lot of extensions on that. Such as `max()`, `min()`, `sort()`, `sorted()`

Comment: I know, but that doesn't make `Comparable` the Swift counterpart for `java.lang.Comparator`. `Comparable` is the Swift equivalent of `java.lang.Comparable`, and sorting closures of type `(T, T) -> Bool` are the Swift equivalent of `java.lang.Comparator`

Comment: @Alexander Completely agree!

Comment: It is sad that the return condition used should be of type Car. Why not just use any other logic so long as the return value is Bool.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to specifically replicate the Java Comparator behavior where it returns a negative number for "less than", zero for "equal", or a positive number for "greater than", you could write a function that returns a `ComparisonResult`.

`ComparisonResult` is an enum with the cases `.orderedAscending`, `.orderedSame`, and `.orderedDescending`.

You could rewrite your function in Swift:

```
extension Car {
    func compare(with other: Car) -> ComparisonResult {
        return self.carId < other.carId 
            ? .orderedDescending 
            : self.carId > other.carId ? .orderedAscending : .orderedSame
    }
}
```

Comment: how can this be used in comparable or compartor?