# C#'s IEqualityComparer<TType> similar or alternative in Swift Language

Tags: c#, swift, asp.net-core, generics, iequalitycomparer

I'm new in swift programming language and my background was .NET Development, I wonder is there any protocol (interface) or abstract class similar to C#'s [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) in swift language?

Note: I'm trying to developing SDK (I already had written it in C# and trying to converting into Swift) that has an interface that you can use it with in generic type. Interface has a method that using IEqualityComparer.

Best regards.

Comment: You should explain more about your situation: Why do you need this? The best way to do this in Swift could be different depending on what you are using this for.

Comment: @Sweeper  I'm trying to developing SDK (I already had written it in C# and trying to converting into Swift) that has an interface that you can use it with in generic type. Interface has a method that using IEqualityComparer.

Comment: @bkulaksiz Remember that languages differ more than their particular spelling of the same set of elements. While C# and Swift *are* relatively similar, the general approach of "take every element in program written in X, find its closest counterpart in Y" almost always ends up with terrible Y code.

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<T>` is just like Java's `Comparator<T>`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45742746/3141234

Comment: Generic interfaces generally don't translate very well into Swift. While `IEqualityComparer` could be translated into a closure type `(T, T) -> Bool` (given you don't need the hash code), I'm not sure about the generic interface in your SDK. I would suggest you redesign the whole thing.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica "is just like" is probably too strong a wording. It's just like `Comparator<T>`, _but for equality only_.

Comment: @Sweeper Not just equality, but also hashing, so depending on the SDK needs, I would suggest `Equatable` or `Hashable` protocols as the closest equivalent.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I misspoke. The specific similarities I wanted to point out were: 1) `IEqualityComparer<T>` is an interface that's implemented by a separate comparator object, not the comparable object itself 2) its equivalent in Swift is just a closure of type `(T, T) -> Bool`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica It is just a closure but unfortunately it seems like closure support isn't as universal in Swift - i.e. there is no `Dictionary` that takes a closure for equality.

Comment: @NetMage [Sure there is.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2430767)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That isn't a `Dictionary` . That is the operator defined by `Equatable` protocol, which as you pointed out, isn't the same as a random closure passed into a `Dictionary` for use as a key comparison operator.

Comment: @NetMage Oh I see what you mean. That's done in a different way: you make a wrapper struct which wraps your objects and conforms to `Equatable` using whatever special meaning of equality that you want. I think that's a better design, because you don't have to pass a comparator in every context that might want to do equating. It's just self-contained within the value.

Comment: @NetMage Here's an example that uses a wrapper object to make a `Set` that hashes/equates objects by their identity, instead of their natural value-based hashing/equality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763847/3141234

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That isn't a Swift Library class. Swift Library doesn't seem to have a native `Dictionary` that supports user specified equality the way C# does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215848/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-netmage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `Equatable` protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable

Comment: It's different. It's the same as the difference between Java's `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes, I think strictly speaking it is equivalent to `Hashable` protocol.

Comment: @NetMage Not quite. `Hashable` is implemented by the thing being hashed. Whereas `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` isn't implemented by `Foo` necessarily (although it can be). It's implemented by separate comparer objects, which can define different ways of checking equalities between two `Foo` objects.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I see what you mean. `Hashable` protocol is like `IEquatable<T>` and not `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @NetMage I don't see a hashcode requirement on the interface, but yeah, you get the point